# Creating an exe for tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have been trying to create a executable for a `tkinter` gui I have created in python 2.7. So far I have tried using `py2exe` and `pyinstaller` but with no luck. When I tried `py2exe` the `cmd` would pop up and then immediately close. When I used `pyinstaller` the executable would "fail to execute script." I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the script I have written for my gui

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from Tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import ttk
import subprocess


# Import all graph codes.
import graph_1 
import graph_2
import graph_3
import graph_4


def import_csv_data():
    global v
    csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
    print(csv_file_path)
    v.set(csv_file_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

def openfile():
    subprocess.call(['notepad.exe', 'C:/help.txt'])

# Functions for calling graphs.
def graph_1():
    graph_1.display_graph(v.get())

def graph_2():
    graph_2.display_graph(v.get())

def graph_3():
    graph_3.display_graph(v.get())

def graph_4():
    graph_4.display_graph(v.get())


# Read in data buttons.
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text='File Path').grid(row=0, column=0)
v = tk.StringVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)
ttk.Button(root, text='Browse Data Set',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)

# Title and icon of the GUI. 
root.title('Graphs')
root.iconbitmap('C:/icon.ico')
root.geometry("370x118")

#Graph Buttons.
ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 1', command=graph_1).grid(row=3, column=0) 
ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 2', command=graph_2).grid(row=3, column=1)
ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 3', command=graph_3).grid(row=4, column=0)
ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 4', command=graph_4).grid(row=4, column=1)

def new_window():
    # Import all graph codes.
    import graph_1 
    import graph_2
    import graph_3
    import graph_4

    def import_csv_data():
        global v
        csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
        print(csv_file_path)
        v.set(csv_file_path)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    # Define the functions before calling them.
    def doNothing():
        print "nothing"

    # Functions for calling graphs.
    def graph_1():
        graph_1.display_graph(v.get())

    def graph_2():
        graph_2.display_graph(v.get())

    def graph_3():
        graph_3.display_graph(v.get())

    def graph_4():
        graph_4.display_graph(v.get())

    # Read in data buttons.
    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Label(root, text='File Path').grid(row=0, column=0)
    v = tk.StringVar()
    entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)
    ttk.Button(root, text='Browse Data Set',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)

    # Title and icon of the GUI. 
    root.title('Graphs')
    root.iconbitmap('C:/icon.ico')
    root.geometry("370x118")

    #Graph Buttons.
    ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 1', command=graph_1).grid(row=3, column=0) 
    ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 2', command=graph_2).grid(row=3, column=1)
    ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 3', command=graph_3).grid(row=4, column=0)
    ttk.Button(root, text='Graph 4', command=graph_4).grid(row=4, column=1)

    #Menu setup and buttons for new window.
    menu =  Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    subMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
    subMenu.add_command(label="New", command=new_window)
    subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    editMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu=editMenu)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=openfile)

# Menu setup and buttons. 
menu =  Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New", command=new_window)
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=openfile)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: IME with creating python executables, the key is to start with a very minimal program, and when you get that to work, gradually add features until you find the one that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that pyinstaller is not including the icon file.

First of all, with pyinstaller you should get the program working in "one folder" mode before trying "one file" mode.

Try changing 'C:/icon.ico' to just 'icon.ico' and manually putting the icon file in the distribution folder (the folder that contains your .exe).  If this makes the .exe work, you'll need to edit pyinstaller's spec file to tell it to include the icon file.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I tried removing the icon entirely but this did not work either.

Comment: Then maybe it has to do with the subprocess call. Try the same thing with notepad.exe and help.txt. (Even if you don't want to distribute those files, just do this as a test.)